# Implementing example from coroutines TS 2017

Tags: c++, multithreading, coroutine

In the [C++ coroutines TS (2017)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4680.pdf), there is an example of an awaitable object.

```
 template <class Rep, class Period>
 auto operator co_await(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> d) {
    struct awaiter {
        std::chrono::system_clock::duration duration;
        ...
        awaiter(std::chrono::system_clock::duration d) : duration(d){}
        bool await_ready() const { return duration.count() <= 0; }
        void await_resume() {}
        void await_suspend(std::experimental::coroutine_handle<> h){...}
    };

    return awaiter{d};
  }

  using namespace std::chrono;
  my_future<int> h();
  my_future<void> g() {
      std::cout << "just about go to sleep...\n";
      co_await 10ms;
      std::cout << "resumed\n";
      co_await h();
  }
```

Like a typical StackOverflow Question, it will not compile. After cursing quietly for a while, I decided to turn it into a [MCVE] -- for learning.  The code below compiles and runs on VC++17 with /await enabled. I think it probably does approximately what the TS authors intended. Alas, it employs a detached thread. It is not easy to see how that thread could be harvested via `join` or `future::get` or `signal_all_at_thread_exit()` or ...

For example, join cannot be added to a destructor for `awaiter`. In the spawned thread, `h.resume()` causes the awaiter object to be moved into the spawned thread and its (default) constructor called there. So the destructor is called in a different thread than the constructor.

**The question**, aside from "Is this what the TS intended?", is **"Can this be improved, in a reasonably economical way, to tend to the dangling thread?"** (And if so how?)

```
#include <experimental/coroutine>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

namespace xtd = std::experimental;

template <class Rep, class Period>
auto operator co_await(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> dur) {

    struct awaiter {
        using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
        clock::time_point resume_time;

        awaiter(clock::duration dur) : resume_time(clock::now()+dur) {}

        bool await_ready() { return resume_time <= clock::now(); }

        void await_suspend(xtd::coroutine_handle<> h) {
            std::thread([=]() {
                std::this_thread::sleep_until(resume_time); 
                h.resume(); // destructs the obj, which has been std::move()'d
            }).detach(); // Detach scares me.
        }
        void await_resume() {}
    };

    return awaiter{ dur };
}

using namespace std::chrono;

std::future<int> g() {
    co_await 4000ms;
    co_return 86;
}


template<typename R>
  bool is_ready(std::future<R> const& f)
  { return f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready; }

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    auto gg = g();
    cout << "Doing stuff in main, while coroutine is suspended...\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
    if (!is_ready(gg)) {
        cout << "La lala, lala, lala...\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1500ms);
    }

    cout << "Whew! Done. Getting co_return now...\n";
    auto ret = gg.get();
    cout << "coroutine resumed and co_returned " << ret << '\n';
    system("pause");
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be improved, in a reasonably economical way, to tend to the dangling thread?

You can use "thread pool" implementation, instead of on-demand detached thread.

Here is toy example:
https://gist.github.com/yohhoy/a5ec6d4aeeb4c60d3e4f3adfd1df9ebf